# Installing a specific PHP version with macports

Tags: php, macos, symfony, composer-php, macports

I need to mimic my hosting environment, so composer and symfony would respect the environment.

My host is on PHP 7.0.6
And my local environment is  on 7.0.21

During an upgrade doctrine/doctrine-bundle spits out an error

```
Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=7.0.18 but your PHP version (7.0.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for ocramius/proxy-manager 2.0.4 -> satisfiable by ocramius/proxy-manager[2.0.4].
    - ocramius/proxy-manager 2.0.4 requires php 7.0.0 - 7.0.5 || ^7.0.7 -> your PHP version (7.0.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - doctrine/migrations v1.5.0 requires ocramius/proxy-manager ^1.0|^2.0 -> satisfiable by ocramius/proxy-manager[2.0.4].
    - doctrine/migrations v1.5.0 requires ocramius/proxy-manager ^1.0|^2.0 -> satisfiable by ocramius/proxy-manager[2.0.4].
    - ocramius/proxy-manager 2.0.4 requires php 7.0.0 - 7.0.5 || ^7.0.7 -> your PHP version (7.0.6) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for doctrine/migrations v1.5.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/migrations[v1.5.0].
```

I followed these instructions https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort
And tracked the proper version of macports https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/commit/99a636bc52126e82187694ad73c413e22d13f68c

so I ran

```
git clone --single-branch https://github.com/macports/macports-ports.git
cd macports-ports
git checkout 99a636bc52126e82187694ad73c413e22d13f68c
```

But I still have the same version of PHP
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The composer output pretty clearly indicates that your `composer.json` requirements won't run on 7.0.6. Downgrading your local isn't going to fix that.

Comment: It will, because I would've discovered the issue on the local environment before working on it.